# Unable to open xmltree error in flutter when i try to run fresh sample app

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Whenever i try to run flutter app from vscode i get the error

```
W/ziparchive( 6116): Unable to open 'xmltree': No such file or directory
xmltree: error:failed to open file: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
```

The same app run from the android studio.
Also after installation i get the issue when i run command **flutter doctor**.
Error sail aapt file not found in sdk so i copy the aapt2 file in the same folder and rename it with aapt.

Below i share the log file created when i run command **flutter run**

```
Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

command

flutter run

exception
String: Exit code 1 from:  

C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt dump xmltree E:\Flutter App\first_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml

#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:360:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:289:10)
#2      new AndroidApk.fromApk (package:flutter_tools/src/application_package.dart:120:27)
#3      AndroidApk.fromAndroidProject (package:flutter_tools/src/application_package.dart:158:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      ApplicationPackageFactory.getPackageForPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/application_package.dart:46:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:345:56)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:253:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:428:     
37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
#9      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#12     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#15     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#16     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#17     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
#18     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
#19     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#20     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#26     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#27     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#28     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete. 
<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#31     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

**flutter doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at D:\Flutter SDK\flutter
• Framework revision 7a4c33425d (8 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
• Engine revision 52c7a1e849
• Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 36.1.1
• Dart plugin version 183.6270
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.35.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• Redmi Y1 • 8c9968db • android-arm64 • Android 7.1.2 (API 25)

• No issues found!
```

I am using real device to test.

Comment: This is a new created flutter app or a exist flutter app? Will you have this error even when using a new project?

Comment: yes it's newely created app.

Comment: Is it newly created from vscode? I was doing the same and I can deploy to my device successfully. Please try the steps listed here first https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code This will lead you to a new created app and to the basic environment. I also recommend you file a issue to here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Comment: thank you @BarryWang for your support.I solved this issue by updating my Android SDk from 28 to 29..

Comment: Glad to know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @BarryWang for your help.
I solved this issue by upgrading my Android SDk version from 28 API to 29.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried my soultion and it worked for me .

- the probleme in your case is in aapt.exe in the C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\ file
- try to execute it manualy you will get an error most of times a DLL file missing
- what you have to do is to replace the aapt.exe of the your version (sdk 28.0.3) by another appt.exe of other versions < 28.0.3
- you can find the sdks versions installed in your android studio in this folder ""C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\ ""
- if you dont have others versions install one of theme ( < 28.0.3 )
- in my case my applications was running by sdk 29.0.1 it generate that probleme so i took aapt.exe from 28.0.3 and i past it in sdk 29.0.1

---

good luck